# Prove the isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

$$\left[S^1 \vee S^1 \vee ... \vee S^1; S^1\right] \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$$

where $\vee$ is a wedge sum and $[X,Y]$ is homotopy class between $X$ and $Y$.

I would appreciate a clear proof of this statement.

Comment: If you would like us to help you then you need to help us. Tell us what you have done to try to solve this problem.

Comment: Well I already can prove that $[S^1, S^1]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. And maybe later would work some induction...

Comment: And what exactly is a fundamental group? We didn't discuss it yet during my classes and while searching the internet I found the definition that is quite sophisticated and I don't really get what it is.

Comment: @Anne, sorry, my fault. Forget my comment.

Comment: Please, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\bigvee^n_{i = 1} S^1 = * \cup_{\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1} \varphi} \bigsqcup^n_{i = 1} D^1 = C(\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1} \varphi)$ where $\varphi$ attaches $D^1$ along $\partial D^1 = S^0$ to $*$ because of this we can write down following cofibration sequence:
$$\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1}S^0 \xrightarrow{\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1} \varphi}* \to \bigvee^n_{i = 1} S^1$$
and we may use contravariant Puppe sequence:

$$\ldots\to\left[\Sigma*, S^1\right]\to\left[\Sigma\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1}S^0, S^1\right]\to\left[\bigvee^n_{i = 1} S^1, S^1\right]\to\left[*, S^1\right]\to\left[\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1}S^0, S^1\right]
$$
ofcourse
$\left[\Sigma*, S^1\right], \left[*, S^1\right] = 0$ hence
$\left[\Sigma\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1}S^0, S^1\right]\simeq\left[\bigvee^n_{i = 1} S^1, S^1\right]$ but $\left[\Sigma\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1}S^0, S^1\right] = \left[\bigsqcup^n_{i = 1}S^1, S^1\right] \simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$ because two maps are homotopic iff they are homotopic on every (path) connected component so it boils down to $[S^1, S^1] = \mathbb{Z}$ for $n$-times.